# Sort form field choices by translated labels

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have an array:

`[
   0 => 'translate.label1',
   1 => 'translate.label2',
   2 => 'translate.label1'
]`

which I specify as a `choices` param for field creation.

Now, is it possible to sort these options by **translated** labels? For example, `label1` translated value is *zero*, `label2` - *something*, `label3` - *abracadabra*. Of course, I expect select options to be:

- abracadabra
- something
- zero

I thought to use this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21586886/2324004

But doesn't it involve second translator digest inside view? Any ideas? I'd rather to use something more flexible because my form is based on non-fixed selects count and it would have executed something recursive...

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it in js after data will be uploaded.

Check this topic:

[Javascript to sort contents of select element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278089/javascript-to-sort-contents-of-select-element)

Answer (score 0):

Due to fact the translation occurs inside Twig view, the only solution (right now I'm aware) is to prepare translated and sorted list during form build process by injecting manually `TranslatorInterface` service.

Unfortunately, without overriding widget's template, translation occurs second time, against already translated labels.

Comment: Actually you can disable translation of choices in the view: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-form-and-validator-updates#added-choice-translation-domain-domain-to-avoid-translating-options