# Symfony EntityType sorted translations

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-forms

I have a form with an `EntityType` field as such :

```php
$builder->add('myField', EntityType::class, [
        'class' => 'App:MyEntity',
        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
          return $er->createQueryBuilder('entity')
            ->where('entity.some_value LIKE :value')
            ->setParameter('value', $some_filter)
            ->orderBy('entity.name', 'ASC');
        },
        'choice_translation_domain' => true,
        'choice_label' => 'name',
        'multiple' => false,
        'expanded' => false,
      ]);
```

This renders as a `<select>` element in my HTML form. `<option>` choices in this element are correctly sorted when rendering with the same locale as in the database. However, when rendering with a different locale, the order of options remains the same (as expected) : this results in the options not being alpha-numerically sorted with regards to their translated label.

**How would one implement this so that options are always sorted with regard to the current locale ?**

I assume this could be done using form event listeners, namely `PRE_SET_DATA` or `POST_SET_DATA` but it is not clear to me how I can access and reorder the list of choices generated by the `query_builder`.

Comment: I would normally do that on the frontend. I sometimes use the great Select2 library for stuff like this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/31923222/4346453

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553719/symfony2-sort-order-a-translated-entity-form-field/21586886

Comment: @CyrilMouttet Thank you, that did the trick ! Feel free to add this as an answer, so I can close this question.